Retrieve specific metrics from AWS Cloudwatch with boto3
I have a serverless application, which consists of numerous lambda functions. Each lambda function has a tag "STAGE", which is set either to "production" or "staging". What I need now is to retrieve the data on overall invocations for each production lambda function for the last calendar month (30 days or 4 weeks), with a period of 1 day. I manage to achieve that in the AWS Console (Cloudwatch > Explorer), like shown on the screenshot below:

But the thing is that I need to retrieve this data programmatically to pass it down an ETL pipeline of sorts, that will generate a report with a specific format. I've came up with a following script to retrieve this data:
import datetime
import boto3

client = boto3.client("cloudwatch", region_name="eu-west-1")
from_date = datetime.date.today()
month_ago = from_date - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

response = client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[{
        "Id": "test",
        "MetricStat": {
            "Metric": {
                "Namespace": "AWS/Lambda",
                "MetricName": "Invocations",
                "Dimensions": [{
                    "Name": "STAGE",
                    "Value": "production"
                 }]
             },
             "Period": 86400,
             "Stat": "Sum"
          },
          "ReturnData": True,
   }],
   StartTime=month_ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z"),
   EndTime=from_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00Z")
)


But all it returns me with these params is an empty dataset: { 'MetricDataResults': [{'Id': 'test', 'Label': 'Invocations', 'Timestamps': [], 'Values': [], 'StatusCode': 'Complete'}] ...}
And trying to run with the following Expression "SELECT SUM(Invocations) FROM SCHEMA(\"AWS/Lambda\") WHERE \"STAGE\" = 'production' GROUP BY FunctionName" instead of a MetricStat dict raises a MaxQueryTimeRangeExceed exception, since we're allowed to SELECT the data only on the last 3 hours.
How would I build the query correctly to retrieve the same data with the same filters as I do in the AWS Console in this case? Thanks in advance!

Figuring out the correct parameters to retrieve data from CloudWatch can be quite tricky. I typically start by using the AWS CLI to query for data since it is easy to try various different values. Start by using aws cloudwatch list-metrics to find the correct Namespace, Metric Name and Dimensions, then use aws cloudwatch get-metric-data to test the parameters. Once that is working, you can code the equivalent call using boto3.

Thank you @JohnRotenstein ! Judging by the output of aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace AWS/Lambda --metric-name Invocations STAGE is not a Dimension of these metric entries. I'm not really sure I understand what it actually IS in this case then - provided I can use it in console for filtering (?).

Your screenshot seems to be showing STAGE as a Tag on the resource itself, rather than being something in the metric data. Thus, you would possibly need to filter the results after they are returned from CloudWatch. The Using tags on Lambda functions - AWS Lambda page says "You can use the AWS Resource Groups Tagging API GetResources API operation to filter your resources by tags" to get the Functions with the desired tag.
